# expo-image-picker: Not working after expo update

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm using expo image picker (expo-image-picker) in my project and the same is worked successfully.
when updating my expo to the latest version (updated on May-22-2021), that image picker is not working.
When I choosing an image from library my app gets closed.

Can you please help me why it is..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show how you are using it?

Comment: Thanks for replying, the above issue is fixed, after restarting my expo.